# Size of sets associated to Gaussian integers

Tags: nt.number-theory, inequalities, diophantine-equations, number-fields

Given a non-zero Gaussian integer $z$, we define the set $\mathcal S(z)$
containing all solutions
of $ab+cd=z$ satisfying $\min(\vert a\vert,\vert b\vert)>\max(\vert c\vert,\vert d\vert)$ with $a,b,c,d$ in the set $\mathbb Z[i]$ of Gaussian integers.

The identity
$$2m+1=(2n+(2n^2-m-1)i)(2n-(2n^2-m-1)i)-(2n^2-m)^2$$
and a similar identity for even integers implies that $\mathcal S(z)$ is infinite for every ordinary non-zero integer.

More generally $\mathcal S(z)$ is therefore infinite if $z$ is of the form $i^k s^2m$ for $s$ a non-zero Gaussian integer and for $m$
a non-zero ordinary integer.

*Is there a computable bound on the size of solutions if
$\mathcal S(z)$ is finite?*

(The set $\mathcal S(1+i)$ for example seems to be finite).

Comment: Are you sure about the $s^2$ claim when $s$ is, say, $1+2i$?

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Let me address the case of $z=1+i$. It seems to me that those are the only counterexamples, but a proof I can imagine is now hidden under technical details.

Consider the representation $z=ab+cd$ and define integers $\alpha=|a|^2$, $\beta=|b|^2$, $\gamma=|c|^2$, $\delta=|d|^2$. WLOG we have
$$
  \alpha\geq \beta>\gamma\geq\delta.
$$

Let the vectors $\overrightarrow{OA}$ and $\overrightarrow{OB}$ represent $z$ (fixed) and $ab$ (variable), so that the vector $\overrightarrow{BA}$ represents $cd$. The sides of $OAB$ are $\sqrt2$, $\sqrt{\alpha\beta}$ and $\sqrt{\gamma\delta}$.

Assume that $\alpha\geq \gamma+2$. Then we have
$$
  \sqrt2 \geq \sqrt{\alpha\beta}-\sqrt{\gamma\delta}\geq \sqrt{(\gamma+1)(\gamma+2)}-\gamma,
$$
so
$$
  (\gamma+1)(\gamma+2)\leq (\gamma+\sqrt2)^2,
$$
which provides an explicit upper bound on $\gamma$ (and then a bound on $\alpha$ is also easy).

A similar argument works if $\delta\leq \beta-2$.

It remains to check the case $\alpha=\beta=\gamma+1=\delta+1$. Let $BH$ be an altitude of the triangle. Then $H$ represents an integer multiple of $\frac{1+i}2$, so $AH$ is an integer multiple of $\frac1{\sqrt2}$. However,
$$
  2AH\pm\sqrt2=OH+AH=\frac{OH^2-AH^2}{OH-AH}=\frac{OB^2-AB^2}{\sqrt2}=\pm\frac{2\gamma+1}{\sqrt2},
$$
so that $AH$ is an odd multiple of $\frac1{2\sqrt2}$. This contradiction finishes the proof.

**2.** Some remarks on what to do in the general case.

The first part can be applied similarly, yielding that, if $S(z)$ is infinite, then there are infinitely many solutions with small and fixed values of $\alpha-\beta$, $\beta-\gamma$, and $\gamma-\delta$.

But it seems that one such series should exist. This boils down to some equations similar in vein to Pell equations, which I have no time to dig through right now, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for this proof of finiteness for $1+i$. It took me some time to check it: A few more details would however be helpful (for example, the conclusion that BH is an odd multiple of .. needs one or two additional arguments and does not follow immediatly from your equalities).

Comment: Sorry, I’ve replaced two instances of BH with AH which they were supposed to be.